# How do I display two blocks separately?

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

In my header region, I have two blocks: menu and search. I want to add some other HTML between them. I tried using `{{ content.menu}}`, but it doesn't actually do return anything.

I can split up the content with `{{ content.field_type }}`, but this approach doesn't seem to be working in region.html.twig.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind! By using `{{ dump() }}` I was able to see that I can get the individual blocks by using:

```
{{ elements.search }} 

{{ elements.menu }}
```