# How to split region block render?

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

Is it possible to split the rendering of the blocks in a region ? I have see this question [Drupal 8 - How to split display the blocks separately in region.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237871/drupal-8-how-to-split-display-the-blocks-separately-in-region-html-twig) attempting to solve this by using    `{{ elements.search}}` and I have tried it, but no success yet.

I also tried `{{ elements.children[0] }}` but this failed as well.

Is there a possible way of getting the array element out individually.

Many thanks

Comment: Your block has the enabled in config ?

Comment: Yes the bocks are enabled. Its the header region containing the site branding, Main navigation, Search and User-account blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the blocks in this way:

```
{% for block_key, block in elements if block_key|first != '#' %}
  <b>{{ block_key }}: </b>
  {{ block }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you just need to know the blocks that are present in a given region, you could use this:

```
{{ dump(elements|keys) }}
```

Then you can print each block as:

```
{{ elements.key }}
```